# Bind Literal control inside Gridview from codebehind.

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which contains template fields in which every template field contains a litreal control, and I want to bind that grid view with my DataSet, please look into the code to find more.

Code to create DataSet-

```
DataTable Record = new DataTable();
Record.Columns.Add("zerker");
DataRow dr = Record.NewRow();
dr["zerker"] = "SomeText";   
Record.Rows.Add(dr);
gvCustomres.DataSource = Record;
gvCustomres.DataBind();
```

Code to create GridView-

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomres" runat="server" PageSize="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Zerker">
           <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Literal ID="zerkername" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
     </columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Please help me to find correct way to do this.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your code above is all right if you just want to bind `Column` "zerker" to your `gridiview`.

All you are missing is the `Text Property` for your `Literal` control.

```
<asp:Literal ID="zerkername" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("zerker") %>'>
</asp:Literal>
```